# Are these two writings equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is saying $A$ an element of a power set of the power set of $F$ the same as saying $A$ is a subset of the power set $F?$

Mathematically, $A\subset \mathcal P(F) \Leftrightarrow A\in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(F))$

Comment: Yes, and even more generally $A\subset B\Leftrightarrow A\in\mathcal P(B)$ for any sets $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the definition of **power set** says the following.

> Let $A$ be a set. We define the power set of $A,$ denoted by $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to be the set defined as
> $$\mathcal{P}(A) = \{X \mid X \subseteq A\}.$$

Therefore the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ are the sets $X$ such that $X$ is a subset of $A,$ i.e., $X \subseteq A.$

Hence, saying that a certain object $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ is equivalent to saying that $X \subseteq A,$ i.e.,

$$X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff X \subseteq A.$$

Hence, if you let $A = \mathcal{P}(B)$ for some set $B$ you get

$$X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \iff X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$$